# Excluding a column in a foreach table without losing the data

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach

I need to stop the ID column from displaying in a foreach table generated in html/php but at the same time I still need to refer to the data to edit by ID. Here is the code.

```
$queryz = "SELECT * FROM box WHERE date=CURDATE()";

    print "<table> ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$queryz);
    //return only the first row (we only need field names)
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();  
    print " <tr> ";
    foreach ($row as $field => $value){
    print " <th>$field</th> ";
    } // end foreach
    print " </tr> ";
    //second query gets the data
    $data = $result;
    $data->fetch_assoc();
    foreach($data as $row){
    print " <tr> ";
    foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
    print " <td>$value</td> ";

    } // end field loop
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="print.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '">Print</a></td>';
    print " </tr> ";
    } // end record loop
```

I want it to grab all the columns, but not display the ID column. I still need the ID Data so I can edit the table: `echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '">Edit</a></td>';`

Thanks guys! I've tried filtering via if arrays and excluding the data in the SQL but it won't let me edit the table afterwards. I'm guessing because it is not grabbing the data in the first place.

Comment: You are saying that you don't want to display the ID in the url when you clicked Edit or Print?

Comment: Try `if($field != “ID”) { print " <th>$field</th> "; }`. And do the same with the `$value` line

Comment: I want the SQL to still grab the data but does not display the "ID" column in the foreach table. 
That works for the $field Sean, but the $value won't equal "ID" so it still displays the data, just missing the ID heading.

Comment: if ( $name <> 'ID' ) was all I needed for the value table :) Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the immediate problem by simply ignoring array items whose key is 'ID', like this:

```
$queryz = "SELECT * FROM box WHERE date=CURDATE()";

print "<table> ";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$queryz);

//return only the first row (we only need field names)
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();  

print " <tr> ";
foreach ($row as $field => $value){
  if ( $field <> 'ID' ) {
    print " <th>$field</th> ";      
  }
} // end foreach
print " </tr> ";

//second query gets the data
$data = $result;
$data->fetch_assoc();

foreach($data as $row) {
  print " <tr> ";
  foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
    if ( $name <> 'ID' ) {
      print " <td>$value</td> ";
    }
  } // end field loop
  echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
  echo '<td><a href="print.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '">Print</a></td>';
  print " </tr> ";
} // end record loop
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to use * in your select statements. You should list the fields (columns) you want to retrieve. If you don't include id in the field list, your problem will go away.

Change:

```
$queryz = "SELECT * FROM box WHERE date=CURDATE()";
```

to something like:

```
$queryz = "SELECT field1, field2, etc. FROM box WHERE date=CURDATE()";
```

Comment: So this will remove the column in the table, but it will not grab the column data that I need for editing. I still need it to acquire the data in the query but not display it in the table.